# Snowflake procedure not getting caught by catch block

Tags: javascript, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Why does my snowflake procedure in javascript produces an error and not getting caught by the catch block?

I have a very simple procedure created like this, instead of this going into catch and logging the error it is returning `JAVASCRIPT UNCAUGHT` exception.

Can someone help? Here is the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST()
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$
    var CorrectSQL  =` SELECT COL1, COL2 FROm TABLE_1  LIMIT 10`;
    var InCorrectSQL  =` SELE COL1, COL2 FROm TABLE 2  LIMIT 10`; // SYNTAX ERROR SELE 
    var InsertIntoErrorLog =` INSERT INTO ERROR_LOG VALUES ('ERROR')`;
    try
{
    snowflake.execute({sqlText:CorrectSQL}); 
    snowflake.execute({sqlText:InCorrectSQL}); 
}
  catch(err)
{
    snowflake.execute({sqlText: InsertIntoErrorLog});
    return err;
}
$$
```

Comment: You have a typo: `snowflake.excute`. It's going into the catch block and then getting an error there.

Comment: Hi @Barmar I typed incorrectly in real Procedure this is correct snowflake.execute

Comment: does `snowflake.execute` return a promise?

Comment: If I Correct my InCorrectSQL  like this ` SELE COL1, COL2 FROm TABLE 2  LIMIT 10` then it Works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it works as expected. You have "return err;" command at the end, this is why it returns the error message. Try this one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST()
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$
  var CorrectSQL  = `SELECT COL1, COL2 FROm TABLE_1  LIMIT 10`;
  var InCorrectSQL  = `SELE COL1, COL2 FROm TABLE_2  LIMIT 10`;
  var InsertIntoErrorLog =`INSERT INTO ERROR_LOG VALUES ('ERROR')`;
  try {
        snowflake.execute({sqlText:CorrectSQL }); 
       snowflake.execute({sqlText:InCorrectSQL }); 
   } catch (err) {
        snowflake.execute({sqlText: InsertIntoErrorLog});
       // return err;
    }
$$;
```

Comment: @Gokahn Atil Thanks Sir, I have snowflake.execute statement, i have written before return statement;  It is not executing this statement too. does this mean It would come out of catch and wouldn't execute anything which is before return

Comment: Actually, it works as expected. It writes to the log table (the above code) unless it's getting an error when executing the last query. :)